# DynamoDb Nested Map query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a data structure like this

```
 "Books":{
  {
    "bookId":"Book1"
     "title":"A nice book"
     "subtitle":"A nice book for a child"
      ... some other info
     "bookInfo":{
     "publishDate":1985
     ... some other info
    }
  },
  {
    "bookId":"Book2"
     "title":"A better book"
     "subtitle":"A better book for a child"
      ... some other info
     "bookInfo":{
     "publishDate":2001
     ... some other info
    }
     ... other blocks
  }
     
}
```

So I would like to write a query which filters the books within time range between 1965 to 2000 for example.
I have tried this so far but query is always empty.

```
async function getBooksByTimeRange(tableName,lowerYear,higherYear){
var params = {
TableName : tableName,
KeyConditionExpression:"#bookInfo.publishDate >= :lowerYear and #bookInfo.latitude <= :upperYear",
ExpressionAttributeNames:{
  "#bookInfo":"bookInfo"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
  ':lowerYear': lowerYear,
  ':upperYear': higherYear
}}
let data = await dynamo.query(params)
  data.Items.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      console.log(element.Title + " (" + element.Subtitle + ")");
    });
}
```

Can you help me the create the query which filters nested values?
Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You have #bookInfo but then #address.

But moreover to extract values using a range you want it to be a top-level attribute configured as your sort key.

Comment: There was a mistake with code I have updated it.